# In Spring + Mybatis, how can I get dao method's parameter names in runtime?

Tags: java, java-7, mybatis, spring-mybatis

In code, when I only know the beanId that point to dao object, how can I get method (in dao object) parameter names in runtime?

I'm using Java 7, Spring 4.1.6.RELEASE, Mybatis 3.2.8. And I am completely clueless

```java
String daoBeanId = "IUserDao";
String methodName = "insertUser";

ApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringContextUtil.getApplicationContext();

Object daoInstance = applicationContext.getBean(daoBeanId);
Class daoClass = daoInstance.getClass();

Method method = ReflectUtil.getMethod(daoClass,methodName);

//some code to get this method's parameter names
```

this is different from “Can I obtain method parameter name using Java reflection? ”，because in mybatis，dao object is proxy object，proxy object seems don't have the parameter names information，so it makes this question more complicated and difficult

Comment: this is different from “Can I obtain method parameter name using Java reflection? ”，because in mybatis，dao object is proxy object，proxy object seems don't have the parameter names information，so it makes this question more complicated and difficult

Answer (score 1):

You can try this for Java 8

```
Parameter[] parameters = method.getParameters();
for (Parameter parameter : parameters) {
    System.out.println(parameter.getName());
}
```

This is for earlier Java versions

```
for (int i = 0; i < method.getArgumentTypes().length; i++) {
    LocalVariable variable = 
    method.getLocalVariableTable().getLocalVariable(i);
    System.out.println(variable.getName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8, Please have a look at the below link to get the method parameter names using reflection.

https://www.baeldung.com/java-parameter-reflection